# reading div after javascript load

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I'm having problems parsing information from a forum.
Heres some examples:

1. [Easy](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/966384)
2. [Hard](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/962677)

It would be really easy to get the information as they are displayed in the div where id = "poe-popup-container".

The problem is that that div is only populated when the browser allows you to see the information. That can be easily reproduced by making your browser height really small and looking in the HTML code for the . However, the div will be empty, but as soon you scroll down to see the item it will change.

I'm trying to read the nodes inside the  with htmlagillitypack. The problem is that, as i explained, it only has information when the browser says that you need that information.
So, when you try to download the html, the div is empty.
I've tried to download the page with the web browser too, but the same thing happens.

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
 string page = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Webclient.DownloadData("http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/966384"));
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();           
        doc.LoadHtml(page);            
        HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='poe-popup-container']");            
        MessageBox.Show(node.InnerHtml);
```

Comment: The website loads all js in one bundled and minified file, which pretty tough to crack. The page does load without this div's content, and I have found the code that populates it but the minification makes it very hard to understand. Anyhow, HtmlAgilityPack might not be the tool for this work, unless you find the data inside that div is coming with the HTML itself.

Comment: Dug up a bit more, the content is rendered with json data the comes with the page, you can find it near this line in the source `require(["PoE/Item/DeferredItemRenderer"]` parsing that json will give you the data you need.

Comment: @mot yep i found that javascript too, the problem is that when the string is too big it ends with ... and the information is lost that can be seen in the "hard" example

Comment: Which string is too long? The whole HTML or just the json?

Comment: the json http://pastebin.com/ng5fhKj6 look at the end of the string, that one is from the hard example for the easy one it would work. is there a way to ask the for that complete string?

Comment: Yes, don't convert the data to a string, use deserialize a stream instead.

Comment: oh i see, i was kind of dumb in that one. I was looking into the code via chrome, and thats why the information was cut... when i download the page via webclient i got everything tyvm

Comment: You deleted your [previous duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971841/reading-nodes-in-html) just before posting this one. Please do not do that in the future.

Comment: @andrew barber i asked this question for the first time 5 days ago and i didnt get any answers that duplicate was my second attempt 2 days ago. i didnt get any answers on those so i made another one with more info... i already got my answer mot did it how do i close this one?

Comment: When you don't get any answers, you should improve your question, not delete it and try again. There's nothing to do at this point; the question is already on-hold, which will lead to being closed in a day or so. You can also mark Ondrej's answer below as accepted *if* you think it adequately answers your question. IMO, it does, but that's entirely up to you. :)

Comment: no it doenst... the mot answer is the right one...

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do impossible. Javascript is executed in browser. HtmlAgilityPack is library just for parsing static html - it can't execute javascript.

So why don't you look into browser automation instead ? Try for example http://watin.org/

Comment: ill try when get home ty for the suggestion